# Google conversion tag on order confirmation Opencart 2.3

Tags: javascript, php, tags, opencart

Has anyone done this before.

I need to put this code in opencart 2.3 order confirmation:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = 829815238;
    w.google_conversion_label = "XPd-CKjm0HgQxvPXiwM";
    w.google_conversion_value = 0.00;
    w.google_conversion_currency = "EUR";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

**How to add this values in script?**

```
w.google_conversion_value = 0.00;

w.google_conversion_currency = "EUR";
```

And where can i find confirmation button code to put this - `goog_report_conversion`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set value, you should in controller checkout/{confirm, *}
set value to $data array like

```
$data['google_conversion_value'] = $this->cart->getTotal();
```

same for currency but use

```
$data['google_conversion_currency '] = $this->session->data['currency']
```

than in .tpl file change

```
w.google_conversion_value = <?php echo $google_conversion_value ?>;
w.google_conversion_currency = <?php echo $google_conversion_currency ?>;
```

In .tpl file of your page find "Confirm" button and add

```
onclick="goog_report_conversion(conversion_value)
```

Comment: Super, it helps me, but i put it in checkout.php and in checkout.tpl

Comment: But how to add tax and delivery cost in this total?

Comment: With taxes everything is ok, i check, it is included, question just in delivery.